# How to Fix Mangled Thai Characters

Tags: language, encoding, characters, fonts

I'm having font problems, or maybe character encoding on wordpress.

I am building a Thai website, most of the articles are in the correct language and there is no problem.

But there are a number of articles posted when posting errors in the article letters.

Such as:

https://prnt.sc/vswh8j or https://prnt.sc/vswi15

[image]

As in the picture I have given, some of the first characters can be Thai, but the following characters are like: "à¸µà¹ˆà¹ € à¸ £ à¹ ‡ à¸§à¸" and I don't translate get it in any language.

I don't think my source code supports Thai or something like that. I have tried researching on this problem a lot and tried many ways but to no avail.

Hope you can guide me to fix it. Thank you very much

Comment: Do the characters display ok in the backend/post editor after saving and reopening the editor?  Or is this happening both back and frontend?  If you copy the text into a WordProcessor do you get the broken characters or the original? What is the character encoding setting on your database tables? And are you using a  3rd party font provider  such as google fonts? Edit your question to include these details, even if the answer is _I don't know_

Answer (score 0):

It has many cases:

1. check the character encoding in `wp-config.php`.

   ```php
   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
   define('DB_COLLATE', '');
   ```
2. check database character encoding
3. check if the font you use supporting Thai letters

Comment: changing the character encoding in `wp-config.php` won't change the encoding of the database. It also needs to be multibyte utf8 or various language characters get truncated, e.g. emoji or japanese

Comment: You're right, i meant checking it with database not changing it. but in Arabic language sometimes it works by changing it with same database character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in my [thai font](https://th.fancyfonts.top/ig-font-th.html) website. Took one whole day to find out that I haven't added the meta charset="UTF-8" in the head section.

Adding UTF-8 solved the issue. Hope you might get some idea on how to solve it on wordpress.